# Using 'There,' at beginning of sentence, referring to the location in the last sentence

Tags: grammar

Is the use of 'There,' in the following sentence correct? This feels clunky to me.

Austin went to France. There, some of the buildings were white and others were blue.

Thank you!

Comment: It's 'correct' in that it makes the meaning clear, but you are right in thinking that the idea could be better expressed. However, proofreading is outside the remit of this site.

Comment: It's entirely stylistic. I don't have much of a problem with it. If you add *he saw that* after *there,* it might flow better. And, in fact, *there* would be more appropriate.